# 'He' or 'She'? While writing about past/present events of a person who has a gender change?

Tags: pronouns

I was writing a little note on a person who underwent some surgery to change the sex organs. While writing, I was bit confused using a pronoun i.e. which pronoun it takes when we write a post on such person. This person changed from a boy to a girl.

Consider that I interviewed this person and now writing a post.

Examples:

> a) As a kid having *those* characteristics, *s/he* was criticized by *her/his* fellow mates.
>
> b) *S/He* said that *s/he* was not comfortable among *boys* *(this seems tricky)*
>
> c) When declared about *his/her* feelings, *s/he* was being treated very differently
>
> d) When you ask about how s/he felt in past, s/he does not hesitate telling the truth *(this one is annoying!)*

Comment: Very interesting question, Sir! I am eagerly waiting for the answer.

Comment: Have you or will you consider any other options than simply _He_ and _She_?

Comment: I can but when I'm writing a note, it's difficult to avoid (in flow) those pronouns. Which option do I have anyway? Writing a name? But every time it's not possible. @CipherBot

Answer (score 2):

Since this person is a girl now, in general you should use female pronouns.  If you look up articles about celebrities in similar situations, you'll see that this is the normal practice.  [Caitlyn Jenner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caitlyn_Jenner) and [Chelsea Manning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelsea_Manning) are well known examples.

If in doubt though, ask her what she would like.